# SQL select if number is between interval

Tags: sql, wordpress, mysqli, intervals

I'm busy building up a catalog site for a client of mine, and need to tweek the search a bit.

The catalog contains a whole bunch of products. Each product has the ability to contain a single, multiple and an interval of itemnumbers. To clarify that a bit I've listed a couple of examples beneath.

**EXAMPLE 1)**
*multiple itemnumbers*

itemnumber = 100, 105, 109, 200

**EXAMPLE 2)**
*an interval of itemnumbers*

itemnumber = 100 - 110

**EXAMPLE 3)**
*A combination*

itemnumber = 100 - 110, 220, 300 - 310, 400, 401

> **My question is therefore:**
>
> is there a syntax that allows me to check intervals between two
>   numbers separated with ' - '?
>
> If **yes**, any suggestions on how to build up a query that allows me
>   to implement.
>
> If **no**, any directions you would recommend?

---

**Additional info**

The site is build up in WordPress - where itemnumber is a custom meta field. Atm i've hooked into the `pre_posts` and added: - also pasted in pastebin for readability [**pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/95y7EUHg)

`$where .= " OR ID IN ( SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_value LIKE '%" . $wp_query->query_vars['s'] . "%' AND ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID=post_id AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status!='inherit' AND (  {$wpdb->posts}.post_type='produkt' ) ) )";`

The above code simply just checks rather the products meta fields contain the searched word, not specific enough.

---

Comment: What does it mean "to check intervals between two numbers separated with '-'"? Could you add an input and expected output?

Comment: Boris, example 2 -> where to numbers are seperated with ' - '. The input could be `1 - 4` and the output would be sql checking if the searched string macthes either `1` `2` `3` or `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to use a relational logic on an intentionally denormalized database like evil "Wordpress custom meta field" approach.

So, the best you can do is to perform 2 queries:

- One to get all the numbers
- then expand all intervals in PHP (with array_fill(), range() or whatever) to create a regular comma-separated list
- the latter passed to second query into IN()

As a benefit you will get much faster execution

Comment: I was considering this, but was under the impression that fetching all the product + meta ( roughly 100+ products each with a ton of meta ) and then process in PHP would slow down the execution compared to just matching it through SQL (?)

Comment: There is **no matching through SQL** as you aren't using no SQL in your schema at all, but rather a key-value storage. So, you have to follow the same key-value approach you choose. One cannot sit on two chairs at once, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "-" with "AND" and use BETWEEN keyword to get the records:

**Where Column_Name Between 100 AND 110**

Answer (score -1):

You should create your own function that will build the query using CREATE FUNCTION / CREATE PROCEDURE

Create Procedure docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

String functions docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html